# Add badge award date to /badges/{ids}/recipients API result

Tags: feature-request, badges, api

The [`/badges/{ids}/recipients` API function](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badge-recipients-by-ids) returns an array of [*badges*](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/badge), which does not include an award timestamp ([example](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badge-recipients-by-ids#ids=1974&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)).

Currently the only way to obtain timestamps that badges were awarded is to either [query it in SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/303752) (the `Badges` table contains a `Date` column), which isn't up-to-date, or scrape [`/help/badges/{id}`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974), which is inefficient and time-consuming due to throttling.

This is a request to add an optional `award_date` (for example) field to the *badges* API object, present when `user` is present. I believe it makes more sense to add it to *badges* rather than *shallow_user*, as *shallow_user* is used in other API results (which generally include relevant dates where applicable already).